# Does .git folder contain information about deleted commits?

Tags: git, github

So I made a mistake and pushed some sensitive not for public information to github.

After realizing my mistake, I removed the information, re-committed and pushed again.

Then to remove it from git commit history, I rewrote my commit history using `git rebase` and force pushed it to the remote.

Now I have a question, is there any way that data could be extracted from within the `.git` folder? Keep in mind, the remote repository is public.

Comment: See https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/

Comment: Rebase will never "delete" commits. It may make them "orphans" in the sense that they are not reachable by your HEAD or a branch, but they can always be retrieved using reflog assuming they haven't been garbage collected (which usually happens after 30 days)

Answer (score 3):

Every commit is stored in the git repository, even removed. You can see them with:

```
git reflog show
```

You can then checkout a commit with this `reflog` command.
See this documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog

However, a `git gc` can permanently remove unreferenced commit/files.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes. You can retrieve any information stored under the `.git` folder.

Read this detailed answer on how to do it: [How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716)

---

***In general***: As long as the commits are stored in your `.git` folder they can be "recovered" in different ways. If you want to "remove" then from the `.git` folder you have to "clean" you repository.

---

#### How to clean (delete) the old commits from the repository?

```
# remove any old data not related to any commit
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

---

#### ***How to find unreachable file?***

```
# Check and verify that all the objects in the repository are committed
# and print out a list of all the loose (dangling) objects
git fsck --full
```